Conflict Between react-native-ble-plx and @hkpuits/react-native-beacons-manager in React Native App
I am developing a React Native app that involves detecting Bluetooth beacons. The app was working perfectly with the @hkpuits/react-native-beacons-manager package for detecting TI beacons. However, after installing the react-native-ble-plx package to add support for nRF-based chips, the following issues occurred:
Issue with @hkpuits/react-native-beacons-manager:
Detection of the TI beacons, which was previously working without issues, has stopped working. This happened immediately after installing the react-native-ble-plx package, even though I did not change any code related to the @hkpuits/react-native-beacons-manager logic.
Success with react-native-ble-plx:
The react-native-ble-plx package works perfectly for detecting the nRF-based beacons. However, I need both packages to coexist because my app needs to support both TI and nRF beacons.
What I Have Tried:
Verified that the @hkpuits/react-native-beacons-manager code works as expected by removing the react-native-ble-plx package. The TI beacons are detected correctly when ble-plx is not installed.
Reinstalled and re-linked the dependencies to ensure everything is configured correctly.
Checked for potential conflicts in permissions or Bluetooth configurations in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
Environment:
@hkpuits/react-native-beacons-manager: "^1.3.4",
react": "18.3.1",
react-native": "0.75.4",
react-native-ble-plx": "^3.2.1"

